# Someone got a one-letter username

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names

I recall that SE enforces a three-letter minimum on usernames.

But, this doesn't seem to be the case [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/20145/x).

There's no Unicode magic going on, his username really is just one character long:

[image]

Looks like there's a bug somewhere :s

---

After some testing, it seems like there is no length check at all for unregistered accounts. And, when registering an unregistered account, the short username is carried over ([Here's a test account I created and registered](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/20150/x)).

Comment: User X is a spy

Comment: Not really a username until they register

Comment: @random: Yeah, but unregistered accounts sometimes stick around for a long time (I've seen a 1k unreg on Physics). And registration doesn't change your username.

Comment: It might if there's a constraint on the posts table @Manishearth :-).

Comment: A short username is not retained when an account is registered. I recall a case where a user with a 2 letter name, say `XY` on A51 (A51 still allows it, since it runs an old SE engine), was automatically assigned `XY01` when registering on a site.

Comment: @AnonE.Mouse: Nope. See edit.

Comment: (I'll destroy the test account once this gets fixed)

Comment: @Manishearth you should probably edit the Bio of that user to be clear on what you are doing with this test account.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Done, though I doubt that's necessary.

Comment: I used to have a two character username until I started getting random errors one day recently(-ish). In the beginning of SO, there was no length requirement.

Comment: How can you have an unregistered account?

Comment: @MrLister: ? Care to elaborate?

Comment: @MrLister By not registering.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Er, but then you don't exist and you can't set your username anyway.

Comment: @MrLister: not all SE sites require registration to post stuff.

Comment: @Mat Well, I tried several, including Physics, but they all want me to register before I can post.

Comment: @MrLister: No, if you try posting an answer, it asks you to log in, or supply a name+email+homepage.

Comment: I've got dibs on Q!

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Dibs on M.

Comment: I wanted to create Pi, but I only managed to create two "user..." accounts.

Comment: @MrLister Clearly the Pi is a lie...

Comment: We have what appears to be a registered one-letter user name on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/users/36333/v

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Screwed that one up, didn't we? We made a change to the user validation pipeline in April of 2011 (!), but didn't correctly apply it to the unregistered post creation, only the user editing.

The next build will reenable this validation, and it will also fix any existing illegal user names. Thanks for the catch.

Oh, also: It took two years for this to be noticed? Disappoint, people of Meta! ;p

Comment: Out of curiosity, how will it fix them?

Comment: Look at the example account from the question: It gave them back their default user20145, which is the name they would've had if validation had been working.

Comment: Hah, never had I spotted that in `userX` the `X` corresponds to the numeric user ID and is thus fixed and available for use when the text username becomes invalid.